# Finding the highest number using a while loop

Tags: php

I've received some c++ code regarding finding the highest number until the input been set as 0 using the form and while statement, but my echo doesn't appear, even after several times trying to key in the highest number

here some reference of C++ code that need to be transform into php format:
http://prntscr.com/plw8mw

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    Enter First Number:
    <input type="text" name="num1"/><br>
    <input type="submit"><br>
<form/>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $bignum = 0;
        $num = $_POST['num1'];

        while($num != 0) {
            if ($num > $bignum)
                $bignum = $num;
            }
            print "$bignum";
        }
?>

<body/>
<html/>
```

Comment: Improved grammar (somewhat), and improved formatting.

Comment: I did some formatting and it looks like you are missing a closing brace on the `if` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Use echo insteed of print

`echo($bignum);`